# Magento 2 Migration : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: database, magento-2.0.5

I followed http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html for migration. I am facing issue -

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'customer-service-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'`

Checked table for duplicate entries but didn't find any duplicate value.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found an answer yet but it is a duplicate combination between the `request_path` and `store_id` of the `core_url_rewrite` table in the database you are importing from.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same message when saving some products (magento 2.4.3), how did you fix this problem?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200092)